# Outgoing http requests not showing in Fiddler from tcpClient in C#

Tags: c#, http, fiddler, tcpclient

I have a TCP-client written in C#, which sends HTTP requests. When I am sending requests I don't see them in Fiddler. When I send similar requests from Http requester I can see all requests.
What is the reason?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you need to use the TcpClient class rather than just using System.Net.WebClient (which is quite robust for making HTTP requests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler registers itself as the default HTTP proxy. Applications are free to ignore that proxy. Your code needs to cooperate with Fiddler. It needs to find out what proxy is set and use it.

The built-in HTTP classes in .NET do that.

Comment: How can I add this proxy information to the tcpClient?

Comment: That would be a new question.

Comment: To be clear: TCP does not know what a proxy is. You need to build this yourself. TcpClient cannot help with this.

Comment: For HTTP, simplistically, you'd just send your request to the TCP endpoint at `127.0.0.1` on port `8888`. You must ensure that your HTTP request line specifies a fully qualified URL. HTTPS is more complicated.